Каким образом можно получить и исключить все время событий из гугл календаря, используя LEADTEX и Albato
решил вернуться к изучению Телеграмм ботов, наткнулся на сервис LEADTEX. Сделал набросок, при помощи видеорядов. Для связки с гугл календарём используется Albato
Выглядит он так:

Логика создания ивента будет дорабатываться, однако, можно ли каким-либо образом стучатсья по "исходящему веб-хуку" к таблице и получать не занятое время. Подскажите, прошу, очень хотел бы использовать это в дальнейших своих уроках
